# The PowerShell script failed to execute - ServiceFabric

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

I'm new to Service Fabric, and I have difficulties deploying a Service Fabric project to my local cluster.
I keep getting the error: `The PowerShell script failed to execute`

I search for this error, and I read that Visual Studio must be opened as Administrator. I run it as Administrator, so this is not a problem.

I run this command in PowerShell

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Scope CurrentUser
```

but it does not resolve the problem. I keep getting the error with PowerShell script; it's failing on execute.
Can you advise?

Comment: Can you post the full error messages, I assume that this is just the generic message.

Answer (score 0):

Try copy and pasting the script directly into powershell. If it doesn't work you might get a more detailed reason