# The PowerShell script failed to execute - Service Fabric

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, deployment, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to build a Service Fabric project, but I am getting the "The PowerShell script failed to execute" error message.

I am running Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise (15.9.5) as administrator.

I have tried running the following PS code, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51796706/6179181), but it didn't resolve the issue:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Scope CurrentUser
```

I have tried to find any additional info in the Service Fabric Tools area of the "output" tab, as the full text of the error says, but there was nothing there:

> The PowerShell script failed to execute. See the Service Fabric Tools pane in the output window for details.

I am happy to provide any information that could help troubleshoot this issue, as I couldn't find any solution to this problem anywhere.

Comment: Download the StandAlone package here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server then run the CleanServiceFabric.ps1 to clear any prior SF deployments. Then see if you can deploy the cluster

Comment: @Micah_MSFT, thank you for your reply. Did you mean the "CleanFabric.ps1" script? I can't see the "CleanServiceFabric.ps1" script anywhere in the archive.

Comment: Yes sorry CleanFabric.ps1 :)